# How to set image to button in SwiftUI?

Tags: button, swiftui

I want to add a button with an image (on the left), as follows:

[image]

Probably, it seems to be similar to [`setImage(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage) when it comes to `UIButton`.

What I have done so far is:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Add To Cart")
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .padding(.all, 10.0)
}
.background(Color.gray)
.cornerRadius(5.0)
```

And the result is pretty close to the required one:

[image]

However, I couldn't find any property/method in [SwiftUI Button](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button) related to setting an image.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement it as:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5.0) {
        Image("cart")
            .padding(.leading, 10.0)
        Text("Add to Cart")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(.all, 10.0)
    }
}
.background(Color.gray)
.cornerRadius(5.0)
```

Passing `HStack` instead of `Text` would do the trick.

To clarify, adding an image next to the button label is not directly related to the button anymore! When creating a button using [`init(action:label:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/3283501-init) initializer, we are passing `() -> Label` as the second parameter; If you trace the type of `Label`, you'll see that it is basically a `View`, so you are not forced to return a `Text` type for it (as mentioned in the question's code snippet).

Obviously, you could add the image to the right of the label by adding `Text` before the `Image`. Also, if you are aiming to add the text on top of the image (or vice-versa), you could simply replace the `HStack` with a `VStack`.

---

**Furthermore, more reusable code**

You could make your code to be more reusable by creating a custom body `View` for the button. Also, you could create a custom `ViewModifier`:

```
import SwiftUI

// Custom View
struct CustomButtonBody: View {
    private var iconName: String
    private var title: String

    init(iconName: String = "cart", title: String) {
        self.iconName = iconName
        self.title = title
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5.0) {
            Image(iconName)
                .padding(.leading, 10.0)
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.all, 10.0)
        }
    }
}

// Custom Modifier
struct CustomButtonModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
    }
}
```

thus:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    CustomButtonBody(title: "Add to Cart")
}
.modifier(CustomButtonModifier())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Label("Add to cart", systemImage: "cart")
  }
```